# Grid RowEditing - Update not working

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Rowediting is not working on update. I have grid with column in it. If i add a new row then data will bind as we change.

If we try to change the binded data then after update it will not reflect the changed one.

Here is my Grid combo box

> ```
>  xtype: 'grid',
> itemId: 'gdItemId',            
> store: {
>     type: 'webapi',
>     api: {
>         read: 'api/Report/GetTimeDetails'
>     },
>     autoLoad: false,
> },
> columns: [
>     {
>         text: 'Type', dataIndex: 'type_id', width: '12%', editor: combo, renderer: comboBoxRenderer(combo),msgTarget: 'side'
>     }
> ```

```
var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
fields: ["value", "text"],
data: [
  [1, "Deliverys"],
  [2, "Pickup"]
]
});

var comboBoxRenderer = function (combo) {
return function (value) {
    var idx = combo.store.find(combo.valueField, value);
    var rec = combo.store.getAt(idx);
    return (rec === null ? '' : rec.get(combo.displayField));
};
}

var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
store: store,
valueField: "value",
displayField: "text"
});
```

What i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I found some problems here one is , I think has no model defined the model is necessary for use as base in your CRUD, another thing is there no proxy type webapi should be type: 'rest' if you wanna use RESTFULL [ , finally autoSync should be true for update data and another problem you should map the update method for send data to your server api{ read : yourlinkread , update: yourlinktoupdate }

Complete Example

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#cell-editing